# Does the Drake Sword in Dark Souls not scale with any stats?

Tags: dark-souls

I picked up the Drake Sword near the start of the game. It's been great up until now, made the game nowhere near as hard as it would have been without it, it does like 200 damage and it doesn't weigh much.

I'm now in the depths, I've upgraded the sword to +1, but I realised that leveling up my strength isn't increasing my attack power.

Is this because the Drake Sword doesn't scale with stats?

If so, then should I be thinking about leveling up a normal weapon to +5 that scales with stats and using that instead?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46033/13194) if you want some ideas as to which weapon to choose next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the Drake Sword does not scale with your stats, as many other weapons do.

With the sword upgraded to +1, you'll be doing 220 damage. Upgrading it to +5 will take this up to 300 - but at the cost of 40,000 souls and many dragon scales (9, I believe).

Having a +5 weapon that takes your stats into account, while it might give less "base" damage, would deal more damage overall because of your stats and so it should be considered.

However, you would lose the Fire and Magic resistance bonusses granted by the weapon. These are not likely to be significant, but you may notice firebombs and the like dealing more damage than they had before.

Comment: Thanks for the info, think I will just use the drake sword until I find something decent I can level up